# Co-variant array conversion from x to y may cause run-time exception

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, covariance

I have a `private readonly` list of `LinkLabel`s (`IList<LinkLabel>`). I later add `LinkLabel`s to this list and add those labels to a `FlowLayoutPanel` like follows:

```
foreach(var s in strings)
{
    _list.Add(new LinkLabel{Text=s});
}

flPanel.Controls.AddRange(_list.ToArray());
```

Resharper shows me a warning: `Co-variant array conversion from LinkLabel[] to Control[] can cause run-time exception on write operation`.

Please help me to figure out:

1. What does this means?
2. This is a user control and will not be accessed by multiple objects to setup labels,
    so keeping code as such will not affect it.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

What it means is this

```
Control[] controls = new LinkLabel[10]; // compile time legal
controls[0] = new TextBox(); // compile time legal, runtime exception
```

And in more general terms

```
string[] array = new string[10];
object[] objs = array; // legal at compile time
objs[0] = new Foo(); // again legal, with runtime exception
```

In C#, you are allowed to reference an array of objects (in your case, LinkLabels) as an array of a base type (in this case, as an array of Controls). It is also compile time legal to assign *another* object that is a `Control` to the array. The problem is that the array *is not actually an array of Controls.* At runtime, it is still an array of LinkLabels. As such, the assignment, or write, will throw an exception.

Comment: I understand runtime/compile time difference as in your example but isn't conversion from special type to base type legal? Moreover I have typed list and I am going from `LinkLabel` (specialized type) to `Control` (base type).

Comment: Yes, converting from a LinkLabel to Control is legal, but that's not the same as what is happening here. This is warning about converting from a `LinkLabel[]` to `Control[]`, which is still legal, but can have a runtime problem. All that has changed is the way the array is being referenced. The array itself is not changed. See the issue? The array is still an array of the derived type. The reference is via an array of the base type. Therefore, it is compile time legal to assign an element to it of the base type. Yet the runtime type would not support it.

Comment: In your case, I don't think it's a problem, you're simply using the array to add to a list of controls.

Comment: If anyone's wondering why arrays are wrongely covariant in C# here is [Eric Lippert's explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx) : _It was added to the CLR because Java requires it and the CLR designers wanted to be able to support Java-like languages. We then up and added it to C# because it was in the CLR. This decision was quite controversial at the time and I am not very happy about it, but there’s nothing we can do about it now._

Answer (score 14):

I'll try to clarify Anthony Pegram answer.

Generic type is covariant on some type argument when it returns values of said type (e.g. `Func<out TResult>` returns instances of `TResult`, `IEnumerable<out T>` returns instances of `T`). That is, if something returns instances of `TDerived`, you can as well work with such instances as if they were of `TBase`.

Generic type is contravariant on some type argument when it accepts values of said type (e.g. `Action<in TArgument>` accepts instances of `TArgument`). That is, if something needs instances of `TBase`, you can as well pass in instances of `TDerived`.

It seems quite logical that generic types which both accept and return instances of some type (unless it is defined twice in the generic type signature, e.g. `CoolList<TIn, TOut>`) are not covariant nor contravariant on the corresponding type argument. For example, `List` is defined in .NET 4 as `List<T>`, not `List<in T>` or `List<out T>`.

Some compatibility reasons might have caused Microsoft to ignore that argument and make arrays covariant on their values type argument. Maybe they conducted an analysis and found that most people only use arrays as if they were readonly (that is, they only use array initializers to write some data into an array), and, as such, the advantages overweigh the disadvantages caused by possible runtime errors when someone will try to make use of covariance when writing into the array. Hence it is allowed but not encouraged.

As for your original question, `list.ToArray()` creates a new `LinkLabel[]` with values copied from original list, and, to get rid of (reasonable) warning, you'll need to pass in `Control[]` to `AddRange`. `list.ToArray<Control>()` will do the job: `ToArray<TSource>` accepts `IEnumerable<TSource>` as its argument and returns `TSource[]`; `List<LinkLabel>` implements read-only `IEnumerable<out LinkLabel>`, which, thanks to `IEnumerable` covariance, could be passed to the method accepting `IEnumerable<Control>` as its argument.

Answer (score 12):

The warning is due to the fact that you could theoretically add a `Control` other than a `LinkLabel` to the `LinkLabel[]` through the `Control[]` reference to it. This would cause a runtime exception.

The conversion is happening here because `AddRange` takes a `Control[]`.

More generally, converting a container of a derived type to a container of a base type is only safe if you can't subsequently modify the container in the way just outlined. Arrays do not satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 11):

The most straight forward "solution"

`flPanel.Controls.AddRange(_list.AsEnumerable());`

Now since you are covariantly changing `List<LinkLabel>` to `IEnumerable<Control>` there is no more concerns since it is not possible to "add" an item to an enumerable.

Answer (score 5):

The issue's root cause is correctly described in other answers, but to resolve the warning, you can always write:

```
_list.ForEach(lnkLbl => flPanel.Controls.Add(lnkLbl));
```

Answer (score 3):

With VS 2008, I am not getting this warning. This must be new to .NET 4.0.
*Clarification: according to Sam Mackrill it's Resharper who displays a warning.*

The C# compiler does not know that `AddRange` will not modify the array passed to it. Since `AddRange` has a parameter of type `Control[]`, it could in theory try to assign a `TextBox` to the array, which would be perfectly correct for a true array of `Control`, but the array is in reality an array of `LinkLabels` and will not accept such an assignment.

Making arrays co-variant in c# was a bad decision of Microsoft. While it might seem a good idea to be able to assign an array of a derived type to an array of a base type in the first place, this can lead to runtime errors!

Comment: I get this warning from Resharper

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
flPanel.Controls.AddRange(_list.OfType<Control>().ToArray());
```

Comment: Same result as `_list.ToArray<Control>()`.